# How to test a reduced linear model passing through the origin?

Tags: regression, linear-model, goodness-of-fit

For simple ordinary linear regression $y=a+bx$, if I want to use the reduced model $y=bx$, i.e. passing through the origin, how to do statistical tests on the validity of such a linear model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following hopefully gives a few ideas about how you might perform a comparison of a linear model with and without a constant using R.

#### 1. Create simulated data

First, let's create some simulated data.

```
> set.seed(4444)
> x <- 1:100
> y1 <- x + rnorm(100)
> y2 <- 2 + x + rnorm(100)
```

- I've set the seed for the random number generator to make the results replicable.
- `x` is a vector with values 1 to 100.
- `y1` is generated from a model where $y = bx$ (i.e., no need for a constant). Specifically, $y = 1x + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$.
- `y2` is generated from a model where $y = a + bx$  (i.e., constant is required). Specifically, $y = 2 + 1x + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$.

#### 2. Compare fits for data generated without constant

In theory, `y1` should not need a constant to fit the data well, and `y2` should require a constant to fit the data well.
So, let's fit models without (`m1`) and with (`m2`) a constant and compare the fit using `anova`.

```
> y1_m1 <- lm(y1 ~ x-1)
> y1_m2 <- lm(y1 ~ x)
> anova(y1_m1, y1_m2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y1 ~ x - 1
Model 2: y1 ~ x
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     99 108.69                           
2     98 108.68  1 0.0090647 0.0082 0.9281
```

- `lm(y1 ~ x-1)` fits the model without the constant. By default `lm` assumes that a constant is present. Thus, you use `-1` to indicate the absence of the constant.
- Thus, the first two lines save the fits without and with the constant present.
- `anova...` compares the fit of the two models. We can see that the difference in residual sums of squares (`RSS`) is small between the models. The non-significance of the F test could be used to justify the preference of the simpler model without the constant.

#### 3. Compare fits for data generated with constant

Now, let's repeat the above process for the data that was simulated from a model that included a constant.

```
> y2_m1 <- lm(y2 ~ x-1)
> y2_m2 <- lm(y2 ~ x)
> anova(y2_m1, y2_m2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y2 ~ x - 1
Model 2: y2 ~ x
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     99 226.857                                  
2     98  95.419  1    131.44 134.99 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

- Here we see that the model that included the constant has significantly better fit.

Comment: +1 Great. Please add some comments and explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @QiangLi Okay. I've added the update now.